# Unable to use "explicit wait" in the right way

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script using python with selenium to click on some links listed in the sidebar of google maps. When any of the items get clicked, the related information attached to each lead shows up in the right sided area. The script is doing fine. However, I've used hardcoded delay to do the job. How can I get rid of hardcoded delay by achieving the same with `explicit wait`. Thanks in advance.

Link to the site: [website](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=singapore%20bars&rlz=1C5CHFA_enSG722SG726&oq=singapore+bars&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2j0l2.2182j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=1284410,103851311,350&tbm=lcl&rldimm=5846980261362218103&ved=0ahUKEwiwjP_F5PzZAhVJyLwKHSq_A1oQvS4IRTAA&rldoc=1&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9#rlfi=hd:;si:5409787051100677281;mv:!1m3!1d8954.049147902966!2d103.84678164999998!3d1.2876003!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i602!2i431!4f13.1;start:0)

The script I'm trying with:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "replace_with_above_link"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='rlimg0_']"))):
    item.location
    time.sleep(3)  #wish to try with explicit wait but can't find any idea
    item.click()

driver.quit()
```

I tried with `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(item))` instead of hardcoded delay but no luck.

Comment: What is the problem? You cannot click each link in loop without sleep? Or You should wait for new data to render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait until new data displayed after each clcik you may try below:

```
for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='rlimg0_']"))):
    div = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xpdopen']")
    item.location
    item.click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(div))
```

Comment: So damn perfect. Again you did the trick sir. `div = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xpdopen']")` line should be before the for loop. However, where did you find this class `xpdopen`, sir?

Comment: This is the div with details that displayed for each link. I guess you can use its child node or parent/ancestor within the same details popover

Comment: Sorry sir, this line `div = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xpdopen']")` should be just after `item.click()`. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure about this.. `div` is the current details. when you do click on new link you're waiting for new details appearance (staleness of old details). So it should be defined before click. Does my initial code not working? Did you get any exception?

Comment: The way you suggested sometimes works, sometime throws errors in different lines.

Comment: Not always but sometimes this error shows up in different lines `1. Unable to locate element
2. element is not attached to the dom
3. other element would receive the click`.

Comment: The first two might be cause by performance issue: you can use `div = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='xpdopen']")))` , but the third one is strange as you're clicking `item`, but not `div`... This might be something in your complete code. As I understand provided part of `for` loop is simplified, right?